# Unable to connect with multiple mysql schema in spring batch admin

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-batch-admin

I am new to spring batch and batch admin. I stuck in a scenario where i want to use multiple datasource. i.e. One for batch meta-data and business schema(application tables).

I am using below code in my batch-mysql.properties file.

For batch matadata tables

```
batch.jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
batch.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/batch
batch.jdbc.user=root
batch.jdbc.password=root
batch.jdbc.testWhileIdle=true
batch.jdbc.validationQuery=SELECT 1
batch.drop.script=classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql
batch.schema.script=classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql
batch.business.schema.script=classpath*:business-schema-mysql.sql
```

For application schema

```
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/applicationschema
db.user=root
db.password=root
```

if i remove below line of code
    batch.business.schema.script=classpath*:business-schema-mysql.sql

then i am getting an exception that above property couldn't found.
if keep as it is then it is creating application table in batch matadata schema.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't supply any value to the property `batch.business.schema.script`. Try to leave it like shown below :

batch.business.schema.script=

Also, if you don't want to drop and create batch meta tables every time your application is started, you should set `batch.data.source.init=false` in your batch properties file.

EDIT : This is how my `batch-oracle.properties` file looks like :

```
 batch.database.incrementer.class=org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.OracleSequenceMaxValueIncrementer
 batch.isolationlevel=READ_COMMITTED
 batch.business.schema.script=
 batch.data.source.init=false
 batch.job.service.reaper.interval=6000
 batch.schema.script=classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-oracle10g.sql
 batch.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:mydb
 batch.table.prefix=BATCH_
 batch.lob.handler.class=org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.DefaultLobHandler
 batch.verify.cursor.position=true
 batch.jdbc.validationQuery=SELECT 1 FROM dual
 batch.jdbc.password=mypassword
 batch.jdbc.testWhileIdle=false
 batch.jdbc.user=user
 batch.jdbc.pool.size=5
 batch.drop.script=classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-oracle10g.sql
```

Comment: if i keep as you suggested then i am getting exception.                        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer#0'                               Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CannotReadScriptException: Cannot read SQL script from ServletContext resource    @Ashish

Comment: Hi Ashish, If you have any reference link which uses multiple schema then can you please share with me? I stuck since last many days in this issue..

Comment: Did you try to set the batch.data.source.init to false ? Also you could trick batch admin by just having a simple sql statement in business script like 'Select 1'

Comment: Unfortunately there's not many examples for SBA on the internet. I myself had many hiccups in implementing what you are trying to achieve and I'm not allowed to share my code at work. I'll help to get your problem resolved.

Comment: HI Ashish, Sorry for late communication. I was out. Still, I am not able to connect spring batch project with two database schema. One schema is for application and another schema is for spring batch metadata.

Comment: Could you post your batch-oracle.properties file ?